# Printing Image with brother_ql library in Python on Windows 11: Operation not supported

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print an image on a Brother QL-560 using brother_ql lib in python on Windows 11.

My code looks like this:

```
from PIL import Image
from brother_ql.conversion import convert
from brother_ql.backends.helpers import send, discover
from brother_ql.raster import BrotherQLRaster
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

image = Image.open(r'.\screenshot.png')
size = (720, 1008)
image = image.resize(size)

backend = 'pyusb'
#find printer
#print(discover(backend))
printer = 'usb://0x04f9:0x2027'
model = 'QL-560'

qlr = BrotherQLRaster(model)
qlr.exception_on_warning = True

instructions = convert(
        qlr=qlr, 
        images=[image],
        label='62', 
        rotate='90',    # 'Auto', '0', '90', '270'
        threshold=70.0,    # Black and white threshold in percent.
        dither=False, 
        compress=False, 
        dpi_600=False, 
        hq=True,
        cut=True
)

send(instructions=instructions, printer_identifier=printer, backend_identifier=backend, blocking=True)
```

And it returns the following error:

```
deprecation warning: brother_ql.devicedependent is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
WARNING:brother_ql.conversion:Need to resize the image...
DEBUG:brother_ql.raster:raster_image_size: 720x497
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\labelCreator\listUSB.py", line 42, in <module>
    send(instructions=instructions, printer_identifier=printer, backend_identifier=backend, blocking=True)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\labelCreator\venv\lib\site-packages\brother_ql\backends\helpers.py", line 57, in send
    printer = BrotherQLBackend(printer_identifier)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\labelCreator\venv\lib\site-packages\brother_ql\backends\pyusb.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.dev.set_configuration()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\labelCreator\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 915, in set_configuration
    self._ctx.managed_set_configuration(self, configuration)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\labelCreator\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\labelCreator\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 158, in managed_set_configuration
    self.managed_open()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\labelCreator\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\labelCreator\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 131, in managed_open
    self.handle = self.backend.open_device(self.dev)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\labelCreator\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 804, in open_device
    return _DeviceHandle(dev)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\labelCreator\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 652, in __init__
    _check(_lib.libusb_open(self.devid, byref(self.handle)))
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\labelCreator\venv\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 600, in _check
    raise NotImplementedError(_strerror(ret))
NotImplementedError: Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What am I missing? Are my drivers not compatible?

I have installed libusb-1.0.20 and added MS64/dll to PATH variable and copied libusb-1.0.dll to System32. My Brother QL-560 has all necessary drivers and is working flawlessly with P-Touch Editor.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/wiki/Windows#How_to_use_libusb_on_Windows).